# Maven Dependency project on Google Cloud Build with SonarScanner

Tags: maven, sonarqube, google-cloud-build

I will try to keep the description brief. We have a couple of projects. Some of them are full blown Spring Boot apps, some of them are Maven Dependency projects (used in those Spring Boot apps).
I have set up a Jenkins server for automating pipelines. Jenkins calls Google Cloud Build to build projects/docker images and cache dependencies. It also calls SonarQube in a step. This all works fine for the Spring Boot apps, but the SonarQube step fails for the dependency projects. The error is `Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project projectname: Not inside a Git work tree: / -> [Help 1]`.

The Dockerfile for the project:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY pom.xml settings.xml ./

RUN mvn -s settings.xml dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

# Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn verify -DskipTests -s settings.xml
```

The cloudbuild.yaml:

```
substitutions:
  _IMAGE_NAME: "projectname"
steps:
  - name: "docker"
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |-
        docker pull gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}:$_TAG
        docker pull gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}:latest || true

  - name: "docker"
    args:
      - "build"
      - "-t"
      - "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}"
      - "-t"
      - "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}:$_TAG"
      - "--cache-from"
      - "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}:latest"
      - "--cache-from"
      - "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}:$_TAG"
      - "."

  - name: "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-ce"
      - |-
        mvn -f /pom.xml -s ./settings.xml sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.server.com -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_KEY}

  - name: "gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}"
    args:
      - "mvn"
      - "deploy"
      - "-s"
      - "/settings.xml"

images: ["gcr.io/gcp-project/${_IMAGE_NAME}"]
```

There are two very confusing things. If i run the maven command locally, the analysis completes successfully. Also, if i run the local Google Cloud Build tool (`cloud-build-local`) it also passes.
I have verified that the `.git` folder is not uploaded. It is neither with the Spring Boot apps.
I copied the `settings.xml` from the Jenkins server locally and used that one. Neither the Spring Boot apps or the dependencies define a `sonar-project.properties`.

Is there anyone who can shed some light on this?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I created 2 repositories that are able to replicate this problem:

Non-working: https://github.com/claystation/mvnsonarapp

Working: https://github.com/claystation/mvnsonarappworking

I think the main difference is the dependency project not having `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: In the dockerfile you are not copying the `.git` directory... ?

Comment: Exactly. I do not do that in either project. One works, one does not.

Comment: Are you doing sonar analysis of a maven project ? What are the sonar analysis parameters that you are using during sonar scan ?

Comment: @SouravAtta I am not entirely sure what you mean. But yeah it is a maven project. It just does not have a `main` method and such as it is a dependency project. So it just gets deployed to an artifactory to be downloaded by other projects. I do not use any other sonar analysis params except the ones in the command.

Comment: To do sonar analysis of maven projects, you need to compile it first and then, there are two mandatory sonar-analysis properties you need to use for sonar analysis. Those two are -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/*

Comment: @SouravAtta as you can see in the dockerfile i run `mvn verify`. That is enough for the other project. And i have specified neither of those sonar properties in my other project. But they work fine. So i am really confused why the dependency project is not working.

Comment: Can you try once giving these sonar properties ?

Comment: @SouravAtta unfortunately, no success

Comment: Is it possible for you to make an [MCVE}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? don't forget to remove sensitive information.

Comment: I can try to do that. Let me get back to you.

Comment: @EmilGi Not working version: https://github.com/claystation/mvnsonarapp
Working version: https://github.com/claystation/mvnsonarappworking

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i finally figured it out how to solve this, by doing the MCVE.. Unfortunately not WHY the problem exists.

The main difference between the projects was the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. I thought this might have something to do with having the `spring-boot-starter-parent` parent defined.

I removed the parent part and now my project is passing in Sonar. If there is ever someone who can explain WHY Sonar gives this error with the parent defined but no `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, that would be very helpful.

Thanks!